# How can I make the code take action when swiping to page x on ViewPager2 in Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I'm using androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.

When user swipes to last page, I want the application to run some code.

I want ViewPager2 to run some code when user swipes to last page (locking the swipe and some other code).

How can I make this happen? What method on ViewPager2 should I use?

Comment: show your viewPager code and activity containing the viewPager in your question. in order to give you the best way to place the code according to your implementation

Comment: @BilalRammal I thought I had to use ViewPager2 but I made this happen by running the code by overriding "onResume" of the fragment, and this works. On there I called getActivity(), accessed the viewPager from there and locked the swipe of viewpager using setUserInputEnabled(false). Maybe the question should be deleted as I solved the problem.

Comment: @Coder88 that is a terrible way to implement this use case. Use what is suggested in Sam's answer.

Comment: @mthandr why it's terrible? I run code to make changes on my view on my last fragment.

Comment: @Coder88 you're using the activity reference in the fragment, and casting it to your specific Activity, to access a specific view in the parent activity layout. And you're giving responsability to the fragment itself, in its own lifecycle method, to control the viewpager that its a part of.

Comment: @mthandr Is it unsafe to use if (isAdded()) in the fragment, and then (inside the if-block) refer to some spesific view in the parent activity layout?  (This is what teacher on college does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
binding.viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        super.onPageSelected(position)
            
        if (position == x) {    //you last page index 
            //do what ever you want
        }
    }
})
```

- Helpful reading: https://proandroiddev.com/look-deep-into-viewpager2-13eb8e06e419